# The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton

Tags: android, android-layout, google-play-services, android-xml, google-plus-one

I am following this tutorial https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend to integrate +1 button in my app.

As soon as I put this code in xml I get errors in GraphicalLayout

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
plus:size="standard"
plus:annotation="inline" />
```

I also tried putting `xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"` in parent RelativeLayout, but the same error.

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.


java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneDummyView$zzb.isValid(    at com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneDummyView.zzrJ(    at com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneDummyView.<init>(    at com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.zzg.zza(    at com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton.zzN(    at com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton.<init>(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:438)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:190)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
```

Help !!

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?  Post your build.gradle file.

Comment: sorry using Eclipse for this

Comment: Ahh!  Ok.  Have you imported the google play services library project?

Comment: Ya, I already imported,was running admob banner also in the layout

Comment: Can you post more of your code that you're using, and describe more about how your project is set up?

Answer (score 2):

**Android Studio solution:**

I just got a simple example working by starting with the code from the [gplus-quickstart](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android), and then adding a +1 button using the guide linked in the question.

build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.plustest.daniel.googleplusone" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</manifest>
```

I added `com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton` to the bottom of activity_main.xml, which is based on [main_activity.xml](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/main_activity.xml) from the quick start code:

```
xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
            android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            plus:size="standard"
            plus:annotation="inline" />
```

MainActivity.java, with the added +1 button.

Note that for `URL` I used the Carnegie Mellon School of Computer Science Google+ page.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ResultCallback<LoadPeopleResult>, View.OnClickListener,
        CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener, GoogleApiClient.ServerAuthCodeCallbacks {

    private static final String TAG = "android-plus-quickstart";

    private static final int STATE_DEFAULT = 0;
    private static final int STATE_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private static final int STATE_IN_PROGRESS = 2;

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    private static final String SAVED_PROGRESS = "sign_in_progress";

    // Client ID for a web server that will receive the auth code and exchange it for a
    // refresh token if offline access is requested.
    private static final String WEB_CLIENT_ID = "WEB_CLIENT_ID";

    // Base URL for your token exchange server, no trailing slash.
    private static final String SERVER_BASE_URL = "SERVER_BASE_URL";

    // URL where the client should GET the scopes that the server would like granted
    // before asking for a serverAuthCode
    private static final String EXCHANGE_TOKEN_URL = SERVER_BASE_URL + "/exchangetoken";

    // URL where the client should POST the serverAuthCode so that the server can exchange
    // it for a refresh token,
    private static final String SELECT_SCOPES_URL = SERVER_BASE_URL + "/selectscopes";


    private int mSignInProgress;

    // Used to store the PendingIntent most recently returned by Google Play
    // services until the user clicks 'sign in'.
    private PendingIntent mSignInIntent;

    // Used to store the error code most recently returned by Google Play services
    // until the user clicks 'sign in'.
    private int mSignInError;

    // Used to determine if we should ask for a server auth code when connecting the
    // GoogleApiClient.  False by default so that this sample can be used without configuring
    // a WEB_CLIENT_ID and SERVER_BASE_URL.
    private boolean mRequestServerAuthCode = false;

    // Used to mock the state of a server that would receive an auth code to exchange
    // for a refresh token,  If true, the client will assume that the server has the
    // permissions it wants and will not send an auth code on sign in.  If false,
    // the client will request offline access on sign in and send and new auth code
    // to the server.  True by default because this sample does not implement a server
    // so there would be nowhere to send the code.
    private boolean mServerHasToken = true;

    private SignInButton mSignInButton;
    private Button mSignOutButton;
    private Button mRevokeButton;
    private TextView mStatus;
    private ListView mCirclesListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mCirclesAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> mCirclesList;

    //added:
    private PlusOneButton mPlusOneButton;
    private String URL = "https://plus.google.com/101009371381835899795/posts";

    private static final int PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mSignOutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
        mRevokeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.revoke_access_button);
        mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_status);
        mCirclesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.circles_list);

        //added:
        mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);

        // Button listeners
        mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSignOutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRevokeButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        // CheckBox listeners
        ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.request_auth_code_checkbox)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.has_token_checkbox)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        mCirclesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        mCirclesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, R.layout.circle_member, mCirclesList);
        mCirclesListView.setAdapter(mCirclesAdapter);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mSignInProgress = savedInstanceState
                    .getInt(SAVED_PROGRESS, STATE_DEFAULT);
        }

        mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
        // When we build the GoogleApiClient we specify where connected and
        // connection failed callbacks should be returned, which Google APIs our
        // app uses and which OAuth 2.0 scopes our app requests.
        GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN);

        if (mRequestServerAuthCode) {
            checkServerAuthConfiguration();
            builder = builder.requestServerAuthCode(WEB_CLIENT_ID, this);
        }

        return builder.build();
    }

    //added:
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Refresh the state of the +1 button each time the activity receives focus.
        mPlusOneButton.initialize(URL, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(SAVED_PROGRESS, mSignInProgress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            // We only process button clicks when GoogleApiClient is not transitioning
            // between connected and not connected.
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.sign_in_button:
                    mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signing_in);
                    mSignInProgress = STATE_SIGN_IN;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    break;
                case R.id.sign_out_button:
                    // We clear the default account on sign out so that Google Play
                    // services will not return an onConnected callback without user
                    // interaction.
                    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                    }
                    onSignedOut();
                    break;
                case R.id.revoke_access_button:
                    // After we revoke permissions for the user with a GoogleApiClient
                    // instance, we must discard it and create a new one.
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    // Our sample has caches no user data from Google+, however we
                    // would normally register a callback on revokeAccessAndDisconnect
                    // to delete user data so that we comply with Google developer
                    // policies.
                    Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        switch (buttonView.getId()) {
            case R.id.request_auth_code_checkbox:
                mRequestServerAuthCode = isChecked;
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                if (isChecked) {
                    findViewById(R.id.layout_has_token).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    findViewById(R.id.layout_has_token).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.has_token_checkbox:
                mServerHasToken = isChecked;
                break;
        }
    }

    /* onConnected is called when our Activity successfully connects to Google
     * Play services.  onConnected indicates that an account was selected on the
     * device, that the selected account has granted any requested permissions to
     * our app and that we were able to establish a service connection to Google
     * Play services.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // Reaching onConnected means we consider the user signed in.
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected");

        // Update the user interface to reflect that the user is signed in.
        mSignInButton.setEnabled(false);
        mSignOutButton.setEnabled(true);
        mRevokeButton.setEnabled(true);

        // Hide the sign-in options, they no longer apply
        findViewById(R.id.layout_server_auth).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Retrieve some profile information to personalize our app for the user.
        Person currentUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

        mStatus.setText(String.format(
                getResources().getString(R.string.signed_in_as),
                currentUser.getDisplayName()));

        Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null)
                .setResultCallback(this);

        // Indicate that the sign in process is complete.
        mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
    }

    /* onConnectionFailed is called when our Activity could not connect to Google
     * Play services.  onConnectionFailed indicates that the user needs to select
     * an account, grant permissions or resolve an error in order to sign in.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might
        // be returned in onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());

        if (result.getErrorCode() == ConnectionResult.API_UNAVAILABLE) {
            // An API requested for GoogleApiClient is not available. The device's current
            // configuration might not be supported with the requested API or a required component
            // may not be installed, such as the Android Wear application. You may need to use a
            // second GoogleApiClient to manage the application's optional APIs.
            Log.w(TAG, "API Unavailable.");
        } else if (mSignInProgress != STATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
            // We do not have an intent in progress so we should store the latest
            // error resolution intent for use when the sign in button is clicked.
            mSignInIntent = result.getResolution();
            mSignInError = result.getErrorCode();

            if (mSignInProgress == STATE_SIGN_IN) {
                // STATE_SIGN_IN indicates the user already clicked the sign in button
                // so we should continue processing errors until the user is signed in
                // or they click cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }

        // In this sample we consider the user signed out whenever they do not have
        // a connection to Google Play services.
        onSignedOut();
    }


    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mSignInIntent != null) {
            // We have an intent which will allow our user to sign in or
            // resolve an error.  For example if the user needs to
            // select an account to sign in with, or if they need to consent
            // to the permissions your app is requesting.

            try {
                // Send the pending intent that we stored on the most recent
                // OnConnectionFailed callback.  This will allow the user to
                // resolve the error currently preventing our connection to
                // Google Play services.
                mSignInProgress = STATE_IN_PROGRESS;
                startIntentSenderForResult(mSignInIntent.getIntentSender(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Sign in intent could not be sent: "
                        + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Attempt to connect to
                // get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mSignInProgress = STATE_SIGN_IN;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            // Google Play services wasn't able to provide an intent for some
            // error types, so we show the default Google Play services error
            // dialog which may still start an intent on our behalf if the
            // user can resolve the issue.
            createErrorDialog().show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_SIGN_IN:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // If the error resolution was successful we should continue
                    // processing errors.
                    mSignInProgress = STATE_SIGN_IN;
                } else {
                    // If the error resolution was not successful or the user canceled,
                    // we should stop processing errors.
                    mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
                }

                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    // If Google Play services resolved the issue with a dialog then
                    // onStart is not called so we need to re-attempt connection here.
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(LoadPeopleResult peopleData) {
        if (peopleData.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
            mCirclesList.clear();
            PersonBuffer personBuffer = peopleData.getPersonBuffer();
            try {
                int count = personBuffer.getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    mCirclesList.add(personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
                }
            } finally {
                personBuffer.close();
            }

            mCirclesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error requesting visible circles: " + peopleData.getStatus());
        }
    }

    private void onSignedOut() {
        // Update the UI to reflect that the user is signed out.
        mSignInButton.setEnabled(true);
        mSignOutButton.setEnabled(false);
        mRevokeButton.setEnabled(false);

        // Show the sign-in options
        findViewById(R.id.layout_server_auth).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signed_out);

        mCirclesList.clear();
        mCirclesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason.
        // We call connect() to attempt to re-establish the connection or get a
        // ConnectionResult that we can attempt to resolve.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private Dialog createErrorDialog() {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(mSignInError)) {
            return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                    mSignInError,
                    this,
                    RC_SIGN_IN,
                    new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Google Play services resolution cancelled");
                            mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
                            mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signed_out);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage(R.string.play_services_error)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.close,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Google Play services error could not be "
                                            + "resolved: " + mSignInError);
                                    mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
                                    mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signed_out);
                                }
                            }).create();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CheckResult onCheckServerAuthorization(String idToken, Set<Scope> scopeSet) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Checking if server is authorized.");
        Log.i(TAG, "Mocking server has refresh token: " + String.valueOf(mServerHasToken));

        if (!mServerHasToken) {
            // Server does not have a valid refresh token, so request a new
            // auth code which can be exchanged for one.  This will cause the user to see the
            // consent dialog and be prompted to grant offline access. This callback occurs on a
            // background thread so it is OK to do synchronous network access.

            // Ask the server which scopes it would like to have for offline access.  This
            // can be distinct from the scopes granted to the client.  By getting these values
            // from the server, you can change your server's permissions without needing to
            // recompile the client application.
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(SELECT_SCOPES_URL);
            HashSet<Scope> serverScopeSet = new HashSet<Scope>();

            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                int responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

                if (responseCode == 200) {
                    String[] scopeStrings = responseBody.split(" ");
                    for (String scope : scopeStrings) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Server Scope: " + scope);
                        serverScopeSet.add(new Scope(scope));
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error in getting server scopes: " + responseCode);
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error in getting server scopes.", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error in getting server scopes.", e);
            }

            // This tells GoogleApiClient that the server needs a new serverAuthCode with
            // access to the scopes in serverScopeSet.  Note that we are not asking the server
            // if it already has such a token because this is a sample application.  In reality,
            // you should only do this on the first user sign-in or if the server loses or deletes
            // the refresh token.
            return CheckResult.newAuthRequiredResult(serverScopeSet);
        } else {
            // Server already has a valid refresh token with the correct scopes, no need to
            // ask the user for offline access again.
            return CheckResult.newAuthNotRequiredResult();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUploadServerAuthCode(String idToken, String serverAuthCode) {
        // Upload the serverAuthCode to the server, which will attempt to exchange it for
        // a refresh token.  This callback occurs on a background thread, so it is OK
        // to perform synchronous network access.  Returning 'false' will fail the
        // GoogleApiClient.connect() call so if you would like the client to ignore
        // server failures, always return true.
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(EXCHANGE_TOKEN_URL);

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serverAuthCode", serverAuthCode));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            final String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.i(TAG, "Code: " + statusCode);
            Log.i(TAG, "Resp: " + responseBody);

            // Show Toast on UI Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            return (statusCode == 200);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in auth code exchange.", e);
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in auth code exchange.", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void checkServerAuthConfiguration() {
        // Check that the server URL is configured before allowing this box to
        // be unchecked
        if ("WEB_CLIENT_ID".equals(WEB_CLIENT_ID) ||
                "SERVER_BASE_URL".equals(SERVER_BASE_URL)) {
            Log.w(TAG, "WEB_CLIENT_ID or SERVER_BASE_URL configured incorrectly.");
            Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.configuration_error))
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .create();

            dialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Result after signing in and clicking the +1 button:

[image: Plus One Button Result]

Comment: Your code returns onConnectionFailed with errorCode 17. Do you know the direct cause of this? I may be missing a permission.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder It's hard to say without seeing your code and your project setup.  Note that this is mostly the quick-start code from Google, I just made a small modification to add the +1 button.  If you haven't done so already, follow initial instructions here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

Comment: Hey Daniel, I imported the quick-start code and just ran the project. Whenever I click on the signin button I get the errorCode 17. I noticed that what you posted was directly from that demo as you mentioned. I was hoping you knew something.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder Do you have your project registered in the Google Developer Console?

Comment: Yep! I did the SHA, made sure to use the same package as the app demo, created the new client ID and all that.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder Hmm, well error 17 is sign in failed.  Not sure why it's not working for you, but here is the documentation for the error you are getting: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#SIGN_IN_FAILED

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this and probably make a separate post. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.1'` to your app's gradle