# Android Studio missing GooglePlayServices package despite installed sdk?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-gradle-plugin

Recently I've been trying to create a simplistic login for a small app using google plus.

I've been attempting to get it working for the past week but to no avail. I followed the walkthrough on the google site and also tried implementing the pre-made login activity that android studio support. But either way when I try Im met with a heap of errors despite following the instructions to the best of my ability?

Hereare all my installed sdk's:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQQ2r.png

Here is an example of the errors I encounter when I try to use the premade googleplus login activity from android studio:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYVwU.png

If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it!

Comment: What's your build.gradle file look like?

Comment: Where did you get the code you're trying?  The new  quickstart code is located here: https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android This might also be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451679/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-com-google-android-gms-plus-p/30521539#30521539

Answer (score 0):

You propably didn't add google play services to your dependencies in build.gradle file.

line to add in dependencies:
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'`

Comment: Ok, you didn't post your `build.gradle` so it was first on my mind what could go wrong. It seems that @jlopez posted a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

the java class GooglePlayServicesClient is not exist in the library because it is deprecated already

see this post
[Cannot resolve symbol GooglePlayServicesClient on new Android Studio Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303427/cannot-resolve-symbol-googleplayservicesclient-on-new-android-studio-project)