# PlusOneButton does not render in design view but works fine in real device

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-one

This is the XML tag used.

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
        android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/recommendGooglePlus"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        plus:annotation="inline"
        plus:size="standard" />
```

Project compiles and renders in device without any issues.
But in design view in Android Studio it displays com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton could not be instantiated with NPE.
[image: Rendering Problems]
IDE configuration is as mentioned below:

1. Android Studio 2.1.2
2. Google Play Services Rev 31
3. compileSdkVersion 24
4. buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

What I have tried already:

- Clean / rebuild
- Invalidate caches / Restart AS 2.1.2
  [image: Updated SDK's]

***Is this even possible or should I stick to the simple solution of change PlusOneButton to FrameLayout to check in design view and change it back to PlusOneButton while in text view.***

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451679/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-com-google-android-gms-plus-p

Comment: The code or logic is working fine on a real device. What I am trying to achieve is to fix the rendering issue in AS 2.1.2 in design view. It's annoying me.

Comment: done... Running all the latest libraries and i'm surprised to see this issue.